# Singularities in the Gauss Hypergeometric Function

Tags: transformation, integral-transforms, hypergeometric-function

I am evaluating the following term in a series:

$$I_k = \int\!x^{-3(2k+1)}(1+\lambda x^4)^{-1/2}\,\mathrm dx$$

When I plug this into WolframAlpha, I get the following result:

$$I_k = -\frac{x^{-2(1+3k)}}{2(1+3k)}{}_2F_1\left(\frac 12,-\frac 12 (1+3k);\frac 12 (1-3k);-\lambda x^4\right)$$

**Here's the issue:**  for every odd term $(k = 1, 3, 5, ...)$ both the second and third coefficient of the hypergeometric term is a negative integer, leading one to believe $I_1 = I_3 = ... = \widetilde{\infty}$.  Even after searching for hypergeometric transformations on NIST's site and in other places, this is a tough thing to get around.

**However**, when these values for $k$ are put into the original integral and re-submitted to WolframAlpha, I get a polynomial with some extra terms, leading me to believe a transformation does in fact exist.

For example, take $k = 1$:

$$I_1 = \int\!x^{-9}(1+\lambda x^4)^{-1/2}\,\mathrm dx$$

which becomes

$$I_1 = \frac{1}{16}\left[3\lambda^2\left(\ln x^2 - \ln\left[1+\sqrt{1+\lambda x^4}\right]\right) + \left(3\lambda x^4 - 2\right)x^{-8}\sqrt{1+\lambda x^4}\right]$$

All of the odd terms have these two logarithmic terms followed by a polynomial with some square root stuff (nothing wildly different from term to term).

**Here is my question:** Does anybody have any suggestions for how I would find a general expression for $I_k$?  Even if this means one general expression for even terms and another for odd terms, that would work.

Comment: I must be missing something here.  Aren't the second and third arguments negative for all $k>0$?

Comment: You are correct.  But for even $k$ they are non-integer fractions and for odd $k$ they are integers.  So only half the time it's a problem.

Comment: For odd $k$, see http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.2#ii (formulae 15.2.4 and 15.2.5)

Comment: There's a small problem.  In that page on NIST (and in other sources I've found) it is always mentioned $c$ is less than the negative $a$ or $b$.  I have the opposite case, though, where $c = b+1$.